# Wordpress run simple query_posts and BLANKS out rest of page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am simply baffled by this. It worked before, and I look today and it's broken. Basically, this is a mobile site, and I made a very compact version of the wordpress site. Let me reiterate that it worked for months and now it seemingly randomly doesn't. I'm using this simple query_posts function below and it simply stops the page dead in it's tracks. It doesn't return an error or anything. I look at the source and the entire page just blanks out after query_posts(). There's nothing. I thought maybe it wasn't loading wordpress guts for some reason, but I run another function like wp_reset_query and it passes just fine. Furthermore, I have this exact same code running on a nearly identical site and it works fine. I've been pulling my hair out for two days and I'v exhausted everything I can think of. ANY help would be extremely appreciated

```
/* @package MusicScene Mobile
 * @subpackage NWMS
 */

require_once('../wp-load.php');

global $post;
wp_reset_query();
query_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish'          
        ));
```

Comment: Is your nearly identical site running the same version of WP and / or have either been updated recently? Do they use any of the same plugins? On the same server or sharing a common engine? I only ask because I host many wp sites and one of them has an exploit somewhere that keeps getting me hacked and I have yet to find it. Since you're supposed to keep wp updated, it is possible a recent update made some part of a plugin you use obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!:

```
     /* @package MusicScene Mobile
     * @subpackage NWMS
     */
    require_once('../wp-config.php');
    require_once('../wp-load.php');

    global $post;
    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'post_status' => 'publish'          
            ));
    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Alright.... I might be more confused now than I was before. I thought your code was basically identical to mine, but I plug yours in and it works... WHY?!   And more importantly: if I make posts_per_page 7, it crashes and dies. If I make it 6 it works great. FTR we have hundreds of posts in this category... so it's not running out. What is going on?!?!

Comment: You've gotta run wp_reset_query() after you run the query_posts and have extracted that information out.

Comment: For the record, part (but not all) of the problem was, indeed a plugin. Yet Another Related Posts Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't already done this: disable all plugins/roll back any updates. Since it used to work for months earlier, I do not think of any other possibility other than plugin issues. You might want to check your error log file too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include /wp-config.php as well.

```
require_once('../wp-config.php');
```

Also, **wp_reset_query();** should be added after the query is made: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: I have wp-config, yes. Actually, it's wp-load, that loads wp-config. No problems, no errors.